# Postgres backup and WAL to S3

Tags: postgresql, backup, postgresql-9.1, cloud

We are looking for a solution for the following problem:

We have set up streaming replication so we have a master DB and a slave DB, we want to have basebackups and WAL files sent to our S3 storage periodically.

I have looked at:

- WAL-e which seemed to suit us perfectly, except that it does not support multiple tablespaces, which is a deal breaker.
- Barman supports this but does not support S3, which is also a deal breaker, although it may be possible with pre- and post-backup hooks which I am currently looking into.
- OmniPITR doesn't support S3 either.

Is there an application that does all these things already, or will I have to do some scripting?

Comment: Wal-e now supports tablespaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of research, I ended up using Barman and a custom post-backup script, it works very good!

Comment: I have been looking to dump barman backups into S3 also. Care to share the post-backup script? Thanks, Colin

Comment: We've never gotten around to creating the script, but it's pretty straightforward, you can just read the ENV vars to get the file information you need to upload to S3 :) Here are the docs http://docs.pgbarman.org/ - Look in the bottom for the hooks

Answer (score 1):

You may want to reconsider [`wal-e`](https://github.com/Instagram/wal-e) from Instagram which does just this,

> wal-e Simple Continuous Archiving for Postgres

It supports AWS. And [as of November 2013](https://github.com/wal-e/wal-e/pull/51), shortly after you asked the question, it supports table spaces.